# Event-driven functions in the head section of an XHTML file

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I have a task with some requarements, here is one of them:
*"The scripts shall be coded as event-driven functions in the head section of an XHTML file"*.
Please, specify what is event-driven functions in the head section of an XHTML file

Comment: For the functions, look up javascript events. But to be honest, I'm not sure if you're up to the job if you're unsure of what the head part of an HTML file is.

Answer (score 0):

An XHTML5 template for you to work with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script defer="defer" type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onblur = function(event)
{

}


window.onclick = function(event)
{

}


window.onload = function(event)
{
 alert('Script events in the head section of the example.xhtml file.');
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>

<main>
<h1>Example Page</h1>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```